# Ler arquivo .qrp com php

Tags: php

Estou criando uma aplicação PHP que depende dos dados de outra aplicação (legada). Tais dados são exportados utilizando o formato .qrp, o problema é que nunca vi esse formato antes.

Se alguém souber como transformar o .qrp em uma planilha também seria útil, pois a extração dos dados seria bem fácil.

Answer (score 0):

Existem vários programas que podem gerar reports com ficheiros QRP.

- www.cow2000.co.uk/ - COW2000 Report
- www.guptaworldwide.com/ - Gupta Report Builder File
- www.liberty-systems.com/ - Liberty for Windows Report File

Qual é o programa em questão no seu caso?

(desculpe não colocar os links mas não tenho rep suficiente)